# How to set spring property to a null value from an environment variable

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-properties

Spring properties can be bound from environment variables: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.relaxed-binding.environment-variables

I've tried various forms of `null`, `NULL`, `#{null}` but always end up with `failed to convert java.lang.String to java.time.Duration (caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'null' is not a valid duration)`

How does one set a `null` value from an environment variable?

Comment: If you don't specify the variable value, then whether spring takes its value as null ?

Comment: I have a default set in the ConfigurationProperties file. If I don't specify or set MY_VAR to nothing then the default is used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot set a null value from an environment variable (or any other property source). [This Spring Boot issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/24133) is tracking adding support for binding `null` values.

Comment: It's so pathetic. I need this feature

Comment: @MaksimEliseev why don't you submit a PR then?

Comment: @CamW That's a good point! My bad :(